# Ticks alignment in yaxis in chartjs

Tags: chart.js, yaxis

I'm having some trouble with my right axis ticks with chartjs. You can see in the images I'm adding and removing different axis and it automatically puts them in the left or right side, but sometimes you can see that the numbers in the right axis are not aligned with the gridlines and sometimes they are aligned.

This just happens in the right side and you can see is not because of the information that it brings because there's an example in the images where I select one of the axis that has that error and put it to the left side (Hydrocarbon detector). I'm using Chartjs V2.7.2.

Can anyone help me with this issue please?

[example with 6 axis, hydrocarbon to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUhnN.png)

[example with 5 axis, hydrocarbon to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I28Ht.png)

[example with 6 axis, hydrocarbon to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCqui.png)

[example with 5 axis, hydrocarbon to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1bJe.png)

Comment: Can you create a running code example? On a JSfiddle for example.
It will likely help in reproducing and understanding the issue

Comment: Hi Raquel, sure here I replicated the example https://jsfiddle.net/z0wds1xg/1/ . I would like to know if there's a fix to that version because if I use V2.7.1 it won't happen.